# Visual Studio 2017 - Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does Visual Studio 2017 comes with the Test Manager?

We wanted to upgrade our VS, but before that wanted to confirm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes test manager still comes with visual studio.
Here is a list of features the different versions of Visual Studio 2017 has https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

You can see under the testing tools which versions has what tools.

Answer (score 3):

yes, testing is available in VS2017:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Testmanager is still available in all licence versions. And still packages like NUnit or the MS.TestPlatform can be installed.